# Open graph 'image' content appears empty on debugger and filled in web source

Tags: tags, open-graph

Defining Open Graph meta tags like this for images.

```
global $post; 
$postImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 1200, 9999 ), false );
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $postImg[0]; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="<?php echo $postImg[1]; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="<?php echo $postImg[2]; ?>"/>
```

I get this in my website source:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://elpace.co/event-image.jpg"/>  
<meta property="og:image:width" content="2953"/>    
<meta property="og:image:height" content="4134"/>
```

But this in facebook's Open Graph debugger 
(what scrapper sees).

```
<meta property="og:image" content="">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="">
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using scheduled pots with $post->post_status => 'future'. Scheduled posts can be tricky to handle.

So, the solution is to trick them into being $post->post_status => 'publish' when saved, as shown in this answer:

[Marking future dated post as published](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175/marking-future-dated-post-as-published)

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_attachment_image_url` is not returning the good image size. The function need the name of the image size or a valid image size (1200 x 9999 is not a valid size, just the the way to tell add_image_size cropping definition).

Then the scrapper will be able to scrappe your content. If think there is a minimum and maximum size, and your size seems to be a little bit heavy.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: do you mean 'normal', s'small' or 'large', can you be more specific, please. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can put the image size name, for the name it depends on your theme (or plugins). You can use get_intermediate_image_sizes to discovery them all.

Comment: Thank You, Benoti. I've reading about and started using the 'name' for thumbnail sizes. It turns out that the problem is I'm using 'future' post_status (for an event site. And that is the problem. (meaning the post doesnt exist yet, well kinda... since WP 3.8) that explains why sometimes i got the page not found as og:title. So no og:image, nor og:anything was retrieved.